# Using preprocessor constant with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a preprocessing constant in my code :

```
const unsigned int nbins= _NBINS;
```

And I would like to be able to change it when compiling. For example, I would like to be able to write:

```
cmake build_path [string to change _NBINS]
```

How can I do it using cmake?

Edit: I usually use makefiles so I was a bit confused
For those who ask why I want to do that, it is because I want to autotest my program with various values for _NBINS. I want to recompile my program each time with the new value for _NBINS automatically. _NBINS needs to be a constant because its value is critical for optimisation purposes

Comment: It is not a preprocessing constant. Cmake does not know anything about C++. make is no Cmake

Comment: I think you can't do that. You have to set constants at configure time, i.e., when you run cmake.

Comment: learn how to use autoconf

Comment: The CMake command line argument specifies the value of the string variable. The Makefile generated from the CMake file simply does what the CMake tells it to do. You need to decide what tool your are going to use before asking the question as you are giving a Make command and then asking about CMake. That does not make sense.

Comment: Are you actually using CMake?  If so, start by reading about the [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/configure_file.html) command.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do something similar. But this is clearly [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), you should first explain why you need this! I'm pretty sure there are other better ways to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the compiler flag `-d<desired value>` do the trick for you?

Comment: There is [add_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions). This can depend on some value for example environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! My question was not clear because I am not used to cmake so I mixed it up with my usual practice of makefiles. I edited everything and added a bit of context for those who asked

Comment: `want to recompile my program each time with the new value for _NBINS automatically` You have to configure your project build system, your makefiles to do that. Or use a tool, like cmake, to do that for you. Either way - your question seems unclear or too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I do it using cmake?

You can pass the value of your constant into a **cmake variable** then inside a cmake script get the value of that constant and pass it to compiler.

Call cmake with:

```
cmake build_path -D NBINS=something
```

And inside `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(your_target ...)
target_compile_definitions(your_target PUBLIC NBINS=${NBINS})
```

or before the target:

```
add_compile_definitions(NBINS=${NBINS})
```

Note that in C++ identifiers with leading `_` followed by uppercase letters are reserved. Do not use them in your code. Because of that, note I have removed the leading `_` in the code snippets above.

Answer (score 0):

my workaround for this would be to call

```
cmake build_path -D_NBINS=TRUE
```

and inside CMakeLists.txt

```
if (_NBINS)
        add_definitions(-D_NBINS)
endif()
```

the first line will pass the option to cmake and cmake will pass it further to gcc. I dont know if there is a way to pass it directly to gcc. Tho I think that it should be something like `cmake -D CMAKE_CXXFLAGS='-D_NBINS'`

Comment: Prefer [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) over `add_definitions` because it limits the scope of the definition to a single CMake target.  (It also lets you take the `-D` out of the call, which is nice.)

Comment: true, good point